# A few questions about shaders

Tags: opengl, opengl-es, glsl, shader

I am using opengl shaders.

1. Does count of uniforms affect shader performance? If I pass 5 uniforms or 50 will it matter?
2. Does each shader has its own area where it working on? Or each shader can draw at any point of my application?
3. I often create vertex shader just to pass attributes to fragment shader. What benefit of vertex shader and why not just pass attributes in fragment?

Answer (score 1):

1. I would guess it doesn't (and if it does, only a very minor one). But I don't have any evidence for that, so I might be wrong. This is almost certainly driver-specific.
2. A shader does not draw anything. A shader just processes data. In the pipeline, the rasterizer produces the fragments that are covered by your shape. And these are the fragments that you can potentially draw to. The fragment shader calculates the color (and possibly depth) and the rest of the pipeline decides what to do with the result (either updating the frame buffer, blending, or discarding it altogether). Each draw call can potentially produce a framebuffer update everywhere, not just at some specific locations.
3. This is perfectly fine if the application requires it. The main difference is that vertex shaders process vertices and fragment shaders process fragments. Usually, there are much more fragments than vertices, so the fragment shader is called more often than the vertex shader. Therefore, you should do as much work in the vertex shader as possible. Of course, there are things that you just cannot calculate in a vertex shader.

Comment: There are definitely some mobile GPUs where (1) will matter for performance.